# How to execute UiAutomator test cases programatically in android latest versions

Tags: android, android-instrumentation, android-uiautomator

Below code is working fine when I execute with adb shell command. But if I tried with apk, it is not working. Any help?

## MainActivity.class

```
public void onStart() {

    super.onStart();

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putString("Test", "value");

            try {
                startInstrumentation(new ComponentName("com.example.mypro.uiauto.test", "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"),null, bundle);

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
    });


}
```

## ExampleInstrumentedTest.class

```
@Test
public void pressHome() {

    UiDevice uiDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());
    uiDevice.pressHome();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I landed into the same situation last year in August. So far you cannot trigger instrumented tests from the APK. Here is the link of [Android guide](https://developer.android.com/training/testing/ui-testing/uiautomator-testing#run). Because in that case you can access UI of other applications too. This will be a security issue in the overall android OS where one app is opening another app and doing random stuff which is a threat.

You can execute instrumented tests either via command prompt/terminal or via Android studio only.
The link I've shared, there is a column with heading "Run UI Automator tests on a device or emulator".